# how to filter options on second drop down list after selection on first drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I create a form to enter data and the fields are (Order Type, Group, Name) all of them are drop down list

**1- Order Type -- this is drop down list for 2 choices (A or B)**

then depened on selected Value (A for example) I want to go to database and filter the Options for the second Drop Down list (group)

**2- Group ()**

after that On slected Value form Group also I want to go db and filter option for third field (Name)

**3-Name()**

*all options (item list) come from table and use SQL Server

**Should I get all options and then filter them depend on my selecion??**
**or have to go to db on every selection??**

and please help how to do it on ASP.NET MVC5 by details

UPDATE MY CODE

View

```
@model myModel

<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrderTypeId,Model.AvailableOrderType, required: true)                    
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId,Model.AvailableGroup, required: true)                    
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NameId,Model.AvailableName, required: true)                    
</div>
```

**Group** options depend on **order type** selection and **Name** options depend on **Group** selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cascading dropdown demo:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrderTypeId,Model.AvailableOrderType, required: true)                    
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId,Model.AvailableGroup, required: true)                    
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NameId,Model.AvailableName, required: true)                    
</div>
    @section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $("#OrderTypeId").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetGroup", { OrderType: $("#OrderType").val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#GroupId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, group) {
                    items += "<option value='" + group.Value + "'>" + group.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#GroupId').html(items);
            });
        });
    $("#GroupId").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetName", { Group: $("#Group").val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#NameId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, name) {
                    items += "<option value='" + name.Value + "'>" + name.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#NameId').html(items);
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

action:

```
public ActionResult GetGroup(string OrderType){
  return new Json({List<SelectListItem> type of Group here},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
public ActionResult GetName(string Group){
  return new Json({List<SelectListItem> type of Name here},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```